# How to change implementation at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a few classes that from my client code I need to call. Right now I have a list and then the client has to check the list for the implementation. It is a mess to use.

```
object Adapter {
    val list = listOf(
        A(),
        B()
        ...
    )
}
```

Ideally I would only keep one implementation in memory, but sometimes I need to change between implementations.

Comment: Can you change those classes or are they from some external API?

Comment: They are not, but good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all your classes implement an interface. Since they all implement the same interface you can then assign the concrete instances to the same variable.

```
 interface IWorker {
     fun doWork()
 }
```

Then in the Adapter class you can set which implementation you want to use.

```
object Adapter {
    var worker: IWorker = Default()
}
```

Default represents any of your classes.

```
class Default: IWorker {
    override fun doWork() {}
}
```

Comment: `worker` needs to be a `var` (not `val`) and why not simply: `object Adapter { var worker: IWorker = Default() }` which is more "Kotlin-ish"?